# Displaying count for current_user 'likes' on a 'question' in questions/show.html.erb view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, count, associations

I have an application that allows for users to create questions, create answers to questions, and 'like' answers of others. When a current_user lands on the /views/questions/show.html.erb page I am trying to display the total 'likes' for all answers on that question, for the current_user.

In my Likes table I am collecting the question_id, site_id and the user_id and I have the appropriate associations set up between user, question, answers and likes. I think I just need to call this information the right way, which I can't seem to figure out. All of the below is taking place in the /views/questions/show.html.erb page.

I have tried the following:

```
    <% div_for current_user do %>
        You have liked this question <%= @question.likes.count %> times
    <% end %>
```

Which returns all the 'likes' for the question but not filtered by current_user

```
You have liked this question <%= current_user.question.likes.count %> times
```

Which gives an error of 'undefined method `question'

```
You have liked this question <%= @question.current_user.likes.count %> times
```

Which gives an error of 'undefined method `current_user'

I have tried a couple of other things but they don't make as much sense as the above to me. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
<%= @question.likes.count :conditions => {:user_id => current_user.id} %>
```

Or:

```
<%= current_user.likes.count :conditions => {:question_id => @question.id} %>
```

Or add scope to `Like` model:

```
named_scope :owner, lambda {|user| {:conditions => {:user_id => user.id} } }
```

And call it:

```
<%= @question.likes.owner(current_user).count %>
```

Comment: It is good to understand how sql works. Then it is much easier to get what you want :)

Comment: Thanks man. Check out my most recent question about how to adapt this for /views/likes/create.js.rjs. Need some help.